# How to use JWT with refresh tokens with redis? Lost

Tags: node.js, redis, jwt

I currently use JWT to authenticate however in order to invalidate tokens I added redis (so I don't have to go to MYSQL DB) to blacklist tokens.

While this allows me to invalidate tokens, having the token expire every 20 minutes and making the user sign in again isn't a good experience so I'm trying to implement refresh tokens however I can't think of way to keep things more stateless.

If I implement refresh tokens then won't I be checking the database every 20 minutes  to see if the refresh token is valid. Doesn't this kind of ruin the point of JWT.

I might be over thinking it but is there a way I can keep accessing the MYSQL database to a minimum?

Using redis would be fine but if the server goes down then the blacklisted tokens would be gone.

I really need help. I'm tearing my hair out since our whole authentication system is made around JWT.

Comment: If you are using the `jsonwebtoken` for node they have a method to refresh the token. I haven't used myself, and they don't recommend to do it, netheir do I. But [here](https://gist.github.com/ziluvatar/a3feb505c4c0ec37059054537b38fc48) is their example.

Comment: i can refresh tokens I just dont know how to implement this system with a stateless one. The user cant be signed out every time the short lived token expires because thats just a bad user experience